# Different Output between Stored Procedure and Direct Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that has been working fine for about 8 months of use in preparing data to be sent off to another service.  Two days ago it started truncating the results but there hasn't been any changes to the code in that time period.

Here's the weird part, if I take the statements out of the stored procedure and don't change anything other than making it a direct query, I get the expected result.

Stored Procedure: 5481 Rows
Direct Query: 7490 Rows

I've tried dropping the execution cache, bouncing the server and services but that doesn't fix it.  I have also setup a temporary table to capture any of the prepared batches within the Stored Procedure to compare against the direct query and those all match.

I'm at a loss as to how this is even possible.

Edit:
Code Added Here

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ETL].[spDeliverTransactionalFile]
    @TransactionDate DATE
    ,@MonthNum INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @FiscalPeriodShort VARCHAR(10)
    ,@FiscalQuarterShort VARCHAR(9)
    ,@CalendarMonth INT


CREATE TABLE #MonthNum (
    FiscalPeriodShort VARCHAR(10)
    ,MaxDate DATE
    ,MonthNum INT
    )

IF @TransactionDate IS NULL OR @TransactionDate = '2006-12-31'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MonthNum
    SELECT FiscalPeriodShort
       ,MAX(DateID) AS MaxDate
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DateID) ASC) AS MonthNum
    FROM dimDate
    WHERE FiscalQuarterShort = (
       SELECT FiscalQuarterShort
       FROM dimDate
       WHERE DateID = dbo.TransactionDateID(NULL)
       )
    GROUP BY FiscalPeriodShort
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MonthNum
    SELECT FiscalPeriodShort
       ,MAX(DateID) AS MaxDate
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DateID) ASC) AS MonthNum
    FROM dimDate
    WHERE FiscalQuarterShort = (
       SELECT FiscalQuarterShort
       FROM dimDate
       WHERE DateID = @TransactionDate
       )
    GROUP BY FiscalPeriodShort

END


SELECT @FiscalPeriodShort = FiscalPeriodShort
FROM #MonthNum
WHERE MonthNum = @MonthNum

SELECT @CalendarMonth = MIN(CalendarMonth)
FROM dimDate
WHERE FiscalPeriodShort = @FiscalPeriodShort



SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),l.OrderId) AS OrderCode
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.OrderID ORDER BY dp.Model, dr.RebateID)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),l.factBookingLineSID) AS ItemCode
    ,'Sell' + @FiscalPeriodShort + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@CalendarMonth) AS BatchName
    ,'Sell' AS BatchType
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dp.Model, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS ProductName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dst.SalesTeamName, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS GeographyName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dc.CustomerName, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS CustomerName
    ,SUM(l.CurrentUnitQuantity) AS Quantity
    ,SUM(l.CurrentLineTotal) AS Amount
    ,'USD' AS AmountUnitType
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dd.DateID,101) AS IncentiveDate
    ,'Sell' AS OrderType
    ,dst.SalesTeamID
    ,CASE WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode NOT IN ('Prod1','Prod2','Prod3','Prod4') THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod3' AND l.FranchiseSID IN (1,3) THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod4' AND l.FranchiseSID IN (1,3) THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode IN ('Prod1','Prod2') THEN 'Group2'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod3' AND l.FranchiseSID = 2 THEN 'Group2'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod4' AND l.FranchiseSID = 2 THEN 'Group2'
        ELSE 'UKWN'
        END AS Product_Type
FROM factTransactionLine l
    INNER JOIN dimDate dd ON l.TransactionDateSID = dd.DateSID
    INNER JOIN dimProduct dp ON l.ProductLotSID = dp.ProductLotSID
    INNER JOIN dimSalesTeam dst ON l.CurrentSalesTeamSID = dst.SalesTeamSID
    INNER JOIN dimCustomer dc ON l.CustomerSID = dc.CustomerSID
WHERE l.Deleted = 0 
    AND dd.FiscalPeriodShort = @FiscalPeriodShort
GROUP BY l.OrderId
    ,dp.PartNumber
    ,dp.Model
    ,dc.CustomerName
    ,dd.DateID
    ,dst.SalesTeamName
    ,dst.SalesTeamID
    ,dp.ProductGroupCode
    ,l.FranchiseSID
    ,l.factTransactionLineSID
ORDER BY OrderCode
    ,ItemCode




DROP TABLE #MonthNum
END
```

At Which Point I am running the Stored Procedure using the following syntax:

```
EXEC etl.spDeliverTransactionalFile @TransactionDate = '2018-03-14', @MonthNum = 1
```

Which returns 5481 Rows.

But If I take the Query out of the Stored Procedure as follows:

```
DECLARE @TransactionDate DATE
    ,@MonthNum INT

SELECT @TransactionDate = '2018-03-14'
    ,@MonthNum = 1

DECLARE @FiscalPeriodShort VARCHAR(10)
    ,@FiscalQuarterShort VARCHAR(9)
    ,@CalendarMonth INT


CREATE TABLE #MonthNum (
    FiscalPeriodShort VARCHAR(10)
    ,MaxDate DATE
    ,MonthNum INT
    )

IF @TransactionDate IS NULL OR @TransactionDate = '2006-12-31'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MonthNum
    SELECT FiscalPeriodShort
       ,MAX(DateID) AS MaxDate
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DateID) ASC) AS MonthNum
    FROM dimDate
    WHERE FiscalQuarterShort = (
       SELECT FiscalQuarterShort
       FROM dimDate
       WHERE DateID = dbo.TransactionDateID(NULL)
       )
    GROUP BY FiscalPeriodShort
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #MonthNum
    SELECT FiscalPeriodShort
       ,MAX(DateID) AS MaxDate
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(DateID) ASC) AS MonthNum
    FROM dimDate
    WHERE FiscalQuarterShort = (
       SELECT FiscalQuarterShort
       FROM dimDate
       WHERE DateID = @TransactionDate
       )
    GROUP BY FiscalPeriodShort

END


SELECT @FiscalPeriodShort = FiscalPeriodShort
FROM #MonthNum
WHERE MonthNum = @MonthNum

SELECT @CalendarMonth = MIN(CalendarMonth)
FROM dimDate
WHERE FiscalPeriodShort = @FiscalPeriodShort



SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),l.OrderId) AS OrderCode
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.OrderID ORDER BY dp.Model, dr.RebateID)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),l.factBookingLineSID) AS ItemCode
    ,'Sell' + @FiscalPeriodShort + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@CalendarMonth) AS BatchName
    ,'Sell' AS BatchType
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dp.Model, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS ProductName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dst.SalesTeamName, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS GeographyName
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(dc.CustomerName, ', ', '-'), ',', '-') AS CustomerName
    ,SUM(l.CurrentUnitQuantity) AS Quantity
    ,SUM(l.CurrentLineTotal) AS Amount
    ,'USD' AS AmountUnitType
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),dd.DateID,101) AS IncentiveDate
    ,'Sell' AS OrderType
    ,dst.SalesTeamID
    ,CASE WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode NOT IN ('Prod1','Prod2','Prod3','Prod4') THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod3' AND l.FranchiseSID IN (1,3) THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod4' AND l.FranchiseSID IN (1,3) THEN 'Group1'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode IN ('Prod1','Prod2') THEN 'Group2'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod3' AND l.FranchiseSID = 2 THEN 'Group2'
        WHEN dp.ProductGroupCode = 'Prod4' AND l.FranchiseSID = 2 THEN 'Group2'
        ELSE 'UKWN'
        END AS Product_Type
FROM factTransactionLine l
    INNER JOIN dimDate dd ON l.TransactionDateSID = dd.DateSID
    INNER JOIN dimProduct dp ON l.ProductLotSID = dp.ProductLotSID
    INNER JOIN dimSalesTeam dst ON l.CurrentSalesTeamSID = dst.SalesTeamSID
    INNER JOIN dimCustomer dc ON l.CustomerSID = dc.CustomerSID
WHERE l.Deleted = 0 
    AND dd.FiscalPeriodShort = @FiscalPeriodShort
GROUP BY l.OrderId
    ,dp.PartNumber
    ,dp.Model
    ,dc.CustomerName
    ,dd.DateID
    ,dst.SalesTeamName
    ,dst.SalesTeamID
    ,dp.ProductGroupCode
    ,l.FranchiseSID
    ,l.factTransactionLineSID
ORDER BY OrderCode
    ,ItemCode




DROP TABLE #MonthNum
```

I will get the correct data at 7490 rows.

Comment: Show the specific part of the code causing the issue.

Comment: Updated Original Post with Code.

Comment: Wild guess, but DST just ended a few days ago. Coincidence? Could be there is a subtle time zone issue causing the date to be one hour off (and possibly one day off as a result).

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SELECT FiscalQuarterShort
FROM dimDate
WHERE DateID = dbo.TransactionDateID(NULL)
```

Is non-deterministic

Why not just reassign `@TransactionDate` rather than repeat all that code?

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out to be a Fully Qualified issue.

There was another table added under another schema for dimProduct at some point.  When running the query as is, it was defaulting to dbo.  When running it under the stored procedure it was running it under the alternate schema which is used for ETL.

I always thought that if a schema wasn't defined the Query Engine would default to dbo, but that wasn't the case here.